# Tkinter text widget cursor on particular line

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to implement command console using `Text` widget. In the below code, when I hit "return" key, cursor moves to next line after prompt is inserted. I am not able to make cursor position at the prompt. I tried capturing the x,y co-ordinates but it is also not helping.

```
from Tkinter import *

def getCommand(*args):
    global text
    x_pos = text.xview()[0]
    y_pos = text.yview()[0]
    text.insert(END, "\n")
    text.insert(END, "command>")

root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.pack()
text.insert(END,"command>")
text.focus()
text.bind("<Return>",getCommand)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return `'break'` will prevent `<Return>` processed normally after the callback return.

Try following code.

```
def getCommand(*args):
    global text
    x_pos = text.xview()[0]
    y_pos = text.yview()[0]
    command = text.get('insert linestart', 'insert').replace('command>', '', 1)
    print command
    text.insert(END, "\n")
    text.insert(END, "command>")
    return 'break'
```